# Remove a string and a number from the end of string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Fairly new to PHP and trying to figure out something that I can't get my head around too.

I have a URL below where I want to remove &page_number=x. The page_number variable and the number has to be removed with the function, which will always be at the end of the string.

> http://url.com/search/?location=london&page_number=1

I have tried a few versions of preg_replace but I am not having any luck.

Thanks

Comment: please post what you have tried ?

Comment: @Pratik He had stated he tried `preg_replace`

Comment: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) would also be suitable.

Comment: Share your code, and why do you want to remove this part?

Comment: yes @Zaffy, just want to see what Reg-Exp he had tried!

Comment: As this is a duplicate question I have provided an answer to the linked one that does what you want the way it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'http://url.com/search/?location=london&page_number=1';
$str = preg_replace('/[?&]page_number=\d+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this brilliant solution. I love regular expressions and this does exactly what it needs to. Happy New Year may it bring great fortunes for you :)

Comment: Thank you for your wish :) And thanks @Zaffy for correct editing

Answer (score 1):

```
&page_numer=\d+$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/10

Comment: I think somebody randomly downvoted every answer for this question. All suddenly droped 1 vote.

Comment: Really. My answer has been upvoted and downvoted and i have zero now

Comment: @DmitriKadykov can we somehow bring this for consideration to moderator

Comment: I don't know if it's possible. Maybe this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @DmitriKadykov that we get 3 or 4 more downvotes :

Comment: @DmitriKadykov I would use [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) for that, if I were to ask about something like that

Answer (score 1):

If its the current page it can be done like this:

```
 unset($_GET['page_number']);
 $newStr='?'.http_build_query($_GET);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should remove it without regex's or expensive `explode`:

```php
$str = 'http://url.com/search/?location=london&page_number=1';
$cropped = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '&page_number='));
// $cropped is 'http://url.com/search/?location=london'
```

First, it looks for position of last occurance of &page_number= using `strrpos`, then crops the string up to that occurance using `substr`.

Note: This assumes that the parameter that you want to remove is at the end.

Comment: Can the downvoter please provide me some feedback on what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution. I have tried it and it works also. Much appreciated for your time.